# React Native ios build: Unknown attribute 'ObjectDefinitionBuilder'

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods

I am preparing a build for react native project and I am getting this error:
[image: error]

I was just running this project since weeks and everything was fine, I just installed an npm package, to be specific, I added this package, `react-native-walkthrough-tooltip` which again I believe should not be the cause of the error (I might be wrong).

I tried several solutions related to cleaning the cache but they didn't worked.

I went ahead and I clean the pods that increased my difficulty one more level and I am no more able to install the pods as well with
facing this error for pods:

[image: facing this error for pods]

I have installed node using homebrew and my current node version is v20.5.1, npm : 9.8.1, React Native version: 0.70.5

Can somebody help me to understand what could be went wrong and What should I do to overcome this problem?